# Como validar o CEI em ruby?

Tags: ruby, validação

Para validar CPF e CNPJ eu uso 'brcpfcnpj' no Gemfile.

Mas não encontrei nada para validar o CEI.

Como validar o Cadastro Específico do INSS em Ruby on Rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, aqui vai:

```
def validaCEI(num)

      num = num.gsub(/\D+/,'')  #só digitos

      return false if num.size!=12

      x = []
      numDV = num[-1].to_i

      num = num.chop #remove digito verificador

      [7,4,1,8,5,2,1,6,3,7,4].each_with_index { |peso,i|  x << (peso * num[i].to_i)  }

      soma = 0
      x.each {|n| soma += n }

      dv1 = soma.to_s[-2].to_i + soma.to_s[-1].to_i

      dv2 = 10 - dv1

      (dv2.abs==numDV) ? true : false
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma explicação sobre a validação do CEI pode ser encontrada aqui:

**http://www.igoia.info/index.php/dicas-diversas/115-digitos-verificadores/74-cei-cadastro-especifico-do-inss**

> **Formato:** `EE.NNN.NNNNN/AD`
>
> Onde:
>   `EE` - Número
>   `NNNNNNNN` - Número
>   `A` - Atividade
>   `D` - Dígito Verificador
>
> ### a) Multiplicar os últimos 11 algarismos pelos seus respectivos pesos, conforme abaixo:
>
> Pesos: `7,4,1,8,5,2,1,6,3,7,4`
>   Algarismos: `EENNNNNNNNA`
>
> **Cálculo:**
>
> ```
> 7 * E = X1
> 4 * E = X2
> 1 * N = X3
> 8 * N = X4
> 5 * N = X5
> 2 * N = X6
> 1 * N = X7
> 6 * N = X8
> 3 * N = X9
> 7 * N = X10
> 4 * A = X11
> D (posição do dígito)
> ```
>
> ### b) Somar todos os produtos obtidos no item "a"
>
> ```
> Soma = X1+2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11
> ```
>
> ### c) Com o total obtido no item "b", somar o algarismo da unidade com o algarismo da dezena.
>
> ```
> Total = Dezena de soma + Unidade de soma
> ```
>
> ### d) Subtrair de 10 o algarismo da unidade do obtido no item "c".
>
> ```
> Resultado = 10 - Unidade de Total
> ```
>
> O algarismo da unidade do resultado da subtração será o dígito verificador.
>
> ```
> Digito verificador = Unidade de Resultado
> ```

Uma implementação disso escrita em Ruby:

```
def cei_valid?(cei_str)
    cei = cei_str.gsub(/\D+/, "").chars.map(&:to_i)
    return false unless cei.size == 12

    sum = [7,4,1,8,5,2,1,6,3,7,4].zip(cei).map{|p|p.reduce(:*)}.reduce(:+)
    dv = (10 - (sum%10 + sum/10)).abs % 10
    return dv == cei.last
end
```

Exemplo:

```
cei_valid? "11.583.00249/85"
# => true
```

Comment: Você sabe o significado dos diferentes números (EE, NNNNNNNN, e A)? Quais são os valores possíveis para a atividade, e fazer EE ou NNNNNNNN ter algum significado como os componentes do CNPJ?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, depois de passar muito tempo procurando (sem sucesso) uma função que valide o CEI (Cadastro específico de INSS) via javascript, encontrei a explicação de como validar aqui e criei uma função javascript para validar. Comigo funcionou direitinho, segue o código para quem precisar futuramente.

```
/*
DATA: 08/05/2017
Valida o CEI digitado. 
Faz um cálculo matemático de acordo com o peso: 7,4,1,8,5,2,1,6,3,7,4.
@PARAM: @Obj = OBJ DO CAMPO.
*/
function validarCEI(Obj) {
    //Retira qualquer tipo de mascara e deixa apenas números.
    var cei = Obj.value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

    if (cei == ""){

        return false;
    }

    if (cei.length != 12) {
        alert("CEI digitado é inválido!") ;
        return false;
    }

    var peso = "74185216374";
    var soma = 0;

    //Faz um for para multiplicar os números do CEI digitado pelos números do peso.
    //E somar o total de cada número multiplicado.
    for (i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        var fator = peso.substring(i - 1, i);
        var valor = cei.substring(i - 1, i);
        soma += (fator * valor);
    }
    //Pega o length do resultado da soma e desconta 2 para pegar somente a dezena.
    var len = soma.toString().length - 2;

    //pega a dezena
    var dezena = soma.toString().substring(len);

    //pega o algarismo da dezena
    var algdezena = dezena.toString().substring(0, 1);

    //pega o algarismo da unidade
    var unidade = parseInt(soma) - (parseInt((soma / 10)) * 10);

    //soma o algarismo da dezena com o algarismo da unidade.
    soma = parseInt(algdezena) + unidade;

    //pega o dígito (último número) do cei digitado.
    var digitoCEI = cei.substring(11);
    var digitoEncontrado = 10 - soma;

    if (digitoCEI != digitoEncontrado) {
        alert("CEI digitado é inválido!") ;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Validação do CEI (Cadastro Específico do INSS) em Java.

```
private boolean validaCei(String str_cei) {
      Formato: EE.NNN.NNNNN/AD (12 dígitos)
        Onde:
        EE -        Número
        NNNNNNNN -  Número
        A -         Atividade
        D -         Dígito Verificador

    String peso = "74185216374";
    Integer soma = 0;

    if (str_cei.length() != 12)
        return false;

    //Faz um for para multiplicar os números do CEI digitado pelos números do peso.
    //E somar o total de cada número multiplicado.
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        String fator = peso.substring(i - 1, i);
        String valor = str_cei.substring(i - 1, i);
        soma += (Integer.parseInt(fator) * Integer.parseInt(valor));
    }

    //Pega o length do resultado da soma e desconta 2 para pegar somente a dezena.
    Integer len = soma.toString().length() - 2;

    //Pega a dezena
    Integer dezena = Integer.parseInt(soma.toString().substring(len));

    //Pega o algarismo da dezena
    String algarismoDaDezena = dezena.toString().substring(0, 1);

    //Pega o algarismo da unidade
    Integer unidade = soma - (((soma / 10)) * 10);

    //Soma o algarismo da dezena com o algarismo da unidade.
    soma = Integer.parseInt(algarismoDaDezena) + unidade;

    Integer digitoEncontrado = 10 - soma;

    //Pega o dígito (último número) do cei digitado.
    String digitoCEI = str_cei.substring(11);

    if (digitoCEI.equals(digitoEncontrado.toString()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Em PHP o correto é esse, que equivale ao código em ruby https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17534/13508

```
function cei_valido($cei) 
{
    $cei = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value);

    if (strlen($cei) != 12 || $cei == '000000000000') {
        return false;
    }

    $numbers     = str_split($cei);
    $dv1         = array_pop($numbers);
    $multipliers = [7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 4];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
        $numbers[$i] = $numbers[$i] * $multipliers[$i];
    }
    $sum = array_sum($numbers);
    $dv2 = abs(10 - ($sum % 10 + $sum / 10)) % 10;

    return $dv2 == $dv1;
}
```